# SQL/BIRT how to show entries greater than or equal to 30 days old?

Tags: sql, birt

I am trying to create a BIRT report that shows me tickets 30 days or older from when they were created

I have:

```
SELECT
sta.ticket_no,
sta.status_date
FROM
table1 sta
WHERE sta.status_date <= DATEADD(day, -30, sta.status_date)
```

It runs, but it does not return anything. We definitely have tickets older than 30 days.

Ideally, it would return the ticket number and the date it was created (so long as it was submitted 30 days or more ago)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you calculate the difference using 30 days prior to today - using the native getdate() function

```
SELECT
sta.ticket_no,
sta.status_date
FROM
table1 sta
WHERE sta.status_date <= DATEADD(day, -30, getdate())
```